# number of values of $x$ in inverse trigonometric function

Tags: trigonometry

We have to find the number of values of x satisfying

$\rm arccos x + \rm arccot2x=-\frac{\pi}{2}$

According to me it should be zero as both range of arccos and arcot is always positive .

But the answer given as $2$.

Comment: What is the source of the problem?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee a institute book

Comment: Is there a typo error

Comment: Either the answer is a typo or the question has one. So, definitely a typo.